# Ehcache does not work in application that is clustered

Tags: spring-boot, redis, cluster-computing, spring-cache

My application has a monolithic application that is provided to spring Ehcache.It is worked correctly.It is important to know that the cache config is at service method and the lazy loading is true for all of object that is queried from DB.like this:

```
@Transactional
@Override
@Caching(evict = { @CacheEvict(value = "schoolCache", key = "#school.id")})
public Integer save(School school) {
        // Code here
}
```

It is clear what is saved in the Ehcache is lazy instance of school.There is ModelMapper at controller layer to exchange data between Model and ViewModel like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/load/{Id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public SchoolViewModel load(@PathVariable Integer Id) {
        SchoolViewModel schoolViewModel = ModelMapper.map(schoolService.loadByEntityId(Id), SchoolViewModel.class);
        return schoolViewModel;
    }
```

If SchoolViewModel has an attribute of object that is into school is fetched from DB at controller by ModelMapper.
So i cluster the application and config Ehcache to Redis.
What is the problem? At the beginning when a request query from SchoolService,this service query from DB and because the session of hibernate has been opening,ModelMapper maps Model to ViewModel successfully.at the second time the service method that is called with id as same as id at first time get school object from Redis and there is not session of Hiberante,ModelMapper that want to map an attribute of an object that is into school gets exception.The exception is like this:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not
>   initialize proxy - no Session     at
>   org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:165)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:286)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)

So how do i do? What is the best way that helps me?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Don't use Spring Cache for that. Configure hibernate to properly do 2nd-level caching.

Comment: how hibernate L2 cache  sense a changing in another app .when object change in app 1 and app2 sense that ?

Comment: This will depend on the cache implementation, but most of them support clustering features. This implies Hibernate can coordinate with them even across multiple JVM running on different servers. Both Ehcache and Infinispan support it. BTW they solve several more problems so I'd never advise to do this yourself unless you're doing some R&D yourself.

Comment: Would you give me a link for getting more information

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize all associations that you further need in the service method:

```
schoolService.loadByEntityId(Id), SchoolViewModel.class)
```

So, you have multiple options:

1. You can use `JOIN FETCH` with a JPQL query.
2. You can use `Hibernate.initialize(proxy)` or `Hibernate.unproxy(proxy)`.
3. You can simply navigate the LAZY associations.
4. You can use a DTO projection and you will never bump into any `LazyInitializationException`.